# android: How to make page scrollable vertical also clickable?

Tags: android

I want to make pages in android application below:
, and I'm thinking about 2 ways following but I'm not sure If these are good way 
even enable way.

Could you give me advises about the ways or give me better idea of a way.

**[Want to make]**

1. There are about 10 pages.
2. page 1 : index
    There is lists on pages.
    If you click, you can see the page.
3. page 2 ~ 9: normal page
    just contents ( images or text whatever)

**[Ways I'm thinking about]**

**way A. make 10 layouts**

A layout(call it layout1) is for index pages. The other layout(call it layout2~10) is for other pages. If you click a button in layout1, the layout (from 2 ~ 10) will be showed

**[problem]** I don't know how to enable scrollable in this way.

**ways B. make 1 html (and 1 layout includes a WebView)**

Make index using text and links like this:

```
 <link href="common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       ~~~~~~~
 <div class="pages"></div>  
    <a href="#p1">to page 1 </a>  
    <a href="#p2">to page 2 </a>  
       ~~~~~~~  
 </div>
```

make other pages just using images and name those parts

```
<div class="pages"></div>  
    <a name="p1">  
    <img src="imgP1.jpg">  
 </div>  
 <div class="pages"></div>  
    <a name="p2">  
       ~~~~~~~
```

This way has 2 problems below:

**[problem 1]** How can I set each page's size for the cell phone.

**[problem 2]** In this case, scroll is not horizontal. How can I change it horizontal
               use JavaScript?? If so, How can I use it, and which JavaScirpt should
               I use?

Answer (score 0):

The way A would normally give your app a more native look and feel so I would follow that route.

Make the page1 a ListView. If there are more items in the list as fit on the screen the ListView will automatically allow scrolling.

When an item is clicked a callback method `onItemClick` will be called where you can open the other activities displaying pages 2 to 9.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  I want to scroll like, if you scroll to right on the index page, the page1 be showed, if you scroll to right on the page1, the page2 will be showed, if you scroll to left on the page 1, the index page will be showed and so on.

Comment: In this case you can use a `ViewPager` (it is also available in the support library to support older devices). Implement your pages as fragments and attach them to the view pager.

Comment: Thank so much Henry.  I tried to find some example ViewPager.

Comment: Thank so much Henry.  I tried to find some example ViewPager.  I did it somehow, but I didn't understand it, because I couldn't find good example (web site)of ViewPager which is completed, what I found was uncompleted example.  I'm sorry to late thank you I was keep working during new year..